# Using macroeconomic variables in Market Mix Model

Tags: regression, econometrics, marketing, macroeconomics

I am building a market mix model from proprietary data to predict sales. I would like to include macroeconomic variables as well, such as unemployment rate and consumer confidence.

However, the macroeconomic variables are turning up as oddly strong in my model - though they are not at all correlated with sales, they are turning up in the model with very low p-values, and the model is attributing a huge percentage of sales to these variables.

My data is from before the Covid-19 crisis, when unemployment was very low and varied very little over time. I don't believe that it, and other macroeconomic variables, had an impact on sales anywhere near as strong as my model implies.

I have tried multiple transformations to try to get the real impact of this data to be shown in the model, but they keep coming up way too strong. I can't find any information about this online.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this might be happening and how to correct it?

Comment: Apply a difference transformation to the data. The macroeconomic variable maybe just short-term trend proxy and not actually capable of capturing turning points. Also, look for a sound rationalization for the validity of your explanatory variable (best performed before testing on the current data set).

Comment: The temporal difference between macro variables (e.g., frequently quarterly) with sales data (what's the unit of time?) can be important and lead to artifacts such as you're observing. Eric Ghysels at Duke has written extensively about mixed temporal data models, e.g., https://ideas.repec.org/p/cir/cirwor/2004s-20.html

Comment: The unit of time of the sales data is weekly. We have had multiple issues with the fact that the granularity of time between sales and macroeconomic variables do not match. I will take a look at Eric Ghysels' work - thank you!